# Is there a function to list all uploaded images? How can I add one?

Tags: plugins, php, jquery, uploads, slideshow

Is there a PHP function that will return an array of all of my uploaded images?  Or, failing that, how bout just my uploaded files?

The end goal is to display a slideshow on my homepage: have it rotate through each image, one at a time.  Almost like an animated gif, in an infinite loop/cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uploaded files are stored as attachment post type in WordPress. Use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and query for all attachments:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => null ); 
$all_attachments = get_posts( $args );
```

EDIT - you can also set `post_mime_type` in get_posts to get all of type 'image/jpeg' for example.